# save the modified html in ckeditor and replace it in the original html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

hi i am quite new to JavaScript and j query , I am working on the ckeditor to read the list of html pages from within a folder and show it inside a ckeditor and allow the user to modify and then I am supposed to save this modified content within the actual Html file .

I am able to read the files and show them i the editor appending them to a div tag but how do I  save the modified content is my problem

```
$(function(){       
        editor = null;
        content = "";
        loadSlide = function(slidePath){
            if(editor){
                editor.destroy();
                editor = null;
                $("iframe").remove();
            }

            var xmlhttp;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET",slidePath,false);
            xmlhttp.send();

            var htm = string2dom(xmlhttp.responseText, function(doc, destroy) {
                content = doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
                editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'ckeditor_cntr', {}, content );
            });
        }       
    });
```

Comment: being a div i cant use the default save of the ckeditor as it has no form element as in the text area .. as i researched over the net

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server-side script to handle that. PHP, ASP, any such language, but it cannot be done in JS.

Comment: yes can you please give me more info in how to do it in php . how do i read the content form within the editor which is modified as it is a iframe .